# Implicit function theorem for overdetermined system of nonlinear equations

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, implicit-function-theorem

Consider a sufficiently regular ($C^1$ ?) function
$$F:\mathbb{R}^{m}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$$
with $k>0$. And assume an implicit function $y(x)$ is locally well defined by the condition
$$F(x,y(x))=0$$
I am interested in implicit differentiation techniques which apply in this contest, extending the implicit function theorem.

**EDIT**
My situation of interest is the following.
There is a $C^1$ function
$$G:\mathbb{R}^{m}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$$
where I think of $x\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ as parameters and $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as variables.
Of course, for each $\bar{x},\bar{y}$ such that
$$G(\bar{x},\bar{y})=0$$
The IFT ensures there exists a local function
$$f:U\ni \bar{x}\to V\ni \bar{y}$$
such that
$$G(x,f(x))=0\quad\forall x\in U$$
Moreover, it tells that
$$D_x f(\bar{x})=-[D_y G(\bar{x},f(\bar{x}))]^{-1}[D_x G(\bar{x},f(\bar{x}))]$$

Now, I am interested in the value of $D_x f(\bar{x})$ at points which not only satisfy $G(\bar{x},\bar{y})=0$, but also an additional feasibility condition
$$s(\bar{x},\bar{y})=0\quad\text{where}\quad s:\mathbb{R}^{m}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$$

**My doubt**: Is it enough to consider $D_x f(\bar{x})=-[D_y G(\bar{x},f(\bar{x}))]^{-1}[D_x G(\bar{x},f(\bar{x}))]$ at points where $s(\bar{x},\bar{y})=0$ or does the additional constraint changes the shape of the implicit function $f$, so that we need a different approach?

To get this other with, I thought of considering the function
$$F\equiv\binom{G}{s}:\mathbb{R}^{m}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$
which already "selects" the zeros I am interested in.
Observe that it still makes sense to consider $(\bar{x},\bar{y})\in \mathbb{R}^{m}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that
$$F(\bar{x},\bar{y})=0$$
and, assuming there exists $f:U\ni \bar{x}\to V\ni \bar{y}$
such that $F(x,f(x))=0\quad\forall x\in U$, to ask for implicit differentiation methods to compute the jacobian $D_xf$. Of course, in this case, the IFT cannot be applied off-the-shelf to ensure $f$ exists, nor to compute such a Jacobian. Hence my question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terminology of "selection of correspondences" but I'm assuming $s$ is another constraint on your $(x,y)$ variables? If so, you can just apply IFT on the total function $F$.

Comment: @Leonid Yes it's another constraint. Basically by selection of a correspondence I mean any function mapping any $x$ into  just one element picked from $y(x)$

Comment: @Leonid but how can you apply the IFT on F... It would imply inverting an (n+k)×n jacobian ....

Comment: You have us playing a guessing game here. What rank conditions on your $F$ do you have or are you willing to have? You say the IFT gives $G$. How does it do that?

Comment: The way you defined it, $f$ is only a function of $\bar{x}$ so the expression $D_x f(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ doesn't make sense as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Leonid That is clearly a typo

Comment: @TedShifrin what do you mean the IFT "gives" G? I am only saying I can apply it to G. Of course I am willing to assume the rank condition on its Jacobian

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta: So this is what I gather from the new edit: Let $g$ be the function which satisfies the extra constraint ($s$), and let $f$ be the function without this constraint (so it's the same as your $f$). Your question then essentially boils down to whether $Df|_B = Dg$ where $B$ is the set domain which satisfies all the constraints. So you're asking whether the restriction of the differential of $f$ (not satisfying all the constraints) to the domain satisfying all the constraints is equivalent to the differential of the function satisfying all the constraints?

Comment: @Leonid yes, this is a good way to put it, thanks! Intuitively I think that is not true in general. Hence my question about the implicit differentiation of $g$

Answer (score 2):

The implicit function theorem states that if you have a function $$F: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$$ $$ (x,y) \to F(x,y)$$ Then there exists a function $$y: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$$ such that $F(x,y(x))=0$. Provided the $n \times n$ jacobian matrix given by the entries of $\dfrac{\partial F_i}{\partial y_j}$ (with $i,j=1,...n$) is invertible.

In your case just write $F$ as:

$$F: \mathbb{R}^{m-1} \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$ $$ (x,y) \to \big(G(x,y),s(x,y)\big)$$

Hence you will be able to find a function

$$y: \mathbb{R}^{m-1} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$

such that $G(x,y(x))=0, s(x,y(x))=0$

Provided the $n+1 \times n+1$ Jacobian given by the entries of $\dfrac{\partial F_i}{\partial y_j}$ (with $i,j=1,...n+1$) is invertible.

Also, note that you can reorder your variables however you like. So for instance, you can pick whatever $m-1$ variables you like (out of the original $m+n$ variables in total) and write the other remaining $n+1$ variables in terms of these $m-1$; of course now you will have to check invertibility of a different Jacobian matrix but the exact same reasoning applies. So just to be clear: First choose which variables you want to write in terms of which, and then apply the above process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this approach does not work in my case .... I interpret R^{m} as a space of parameters, and I am interested in the derivatives of the implicit function with respect to these parameters. I cannot just "move" one of the parameters into the variable space, as you do. Notice that in this way I would lose infromation on the derivative of the  implicit function wet to the parameter I am moving.

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta: Okay but you have $n+m$ variables and $n+1$ constraints, so you can't expect for your "parameter space" to be $m$ dimensional. If $s$ (as you have confirmed) is indeed a constraint then in general you will have $m-1$ variables left; my argument is a reflection of that fact. But perhaps I'm missing something about $s$.

Comment: My question was probably vague. Hope it is clearer after the above EDIT